# How long will egg yolks keep?

Tags: eggs, food-preservation

I have one recipe that calls for several egg whites, and no egg yolks that I plan to make soon. I have other recipes that call for more yolks than whites (which I am not planning on using 'soon')...
How long will egg yolks 'keep' in the fridge?
(alternatively/additionally) Can yolks be frozen (for instance, in an ice cube tray) an preserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Egg yolks, optionally covered with water, and in a well sealed container should hold for about 2-3 days in refrigerator.

You may also freeze them, but they require treatment with sugar or salt to prevent the proteins from turning them rubbery, at ratio of about (per the [Egg Board](http://www.incredibleegg.org/egg-facts/eggcyclopedia/f/freezing-eggs)):

- 1/8 teaspoon salt  OR
- 1 1/2 teaspoons sugar or corn syrup

per 1/4 cup of egg yolks (about 4 yolks).

Of course, you then have to adjust whatever recipe you use them upon thawing to account for the sugar or salt already mixed into the yolks.

See also:  [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17139)